# Function doesn't work after object is drag and dropped

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I created this drag and drop list maker using jQuery. The red X is supposed to remove the item on click by fading out the parent div. It works when the element is sitting in the grey box on the right, but after it's dropped, the delete function doesn't work anymore. How do I make this work for items that have been moved to the boxes on the left? Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
$('.draggable').draggable({
revert: "invalid",
stack: ".draggable",
helper: 'clone'
})
$('.droppable').droppable({
accept: ".draggable",
drop: function (event, ui) {
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    // Move draggable into droppable
    draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
    //draggable.css({top: '5px', left: '5px'});
}
})

  $("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('div').fadeOut();
})
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/te4Lqg3f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reapply the event listener when the item is dropped look at the JS below. I added a function which removes the event listener and adds it again. it gets called every time your drop something in a droppable area.

```
       $(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        stack: ".draggable",
        helper: 'clone'
    })
    $('.droppable').droppable({
        accept: ".draggable",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var droppable = $(this);
            var draggable = ui.draggable;
            // Move draggable into droppable
            draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
            //draggable.css({top: '5px', left: '5px'});

           //fire event event listener reset
            reset_event_listeners();
        }
    })

            $("a").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('div').fadeOut();
    })
    });    

    function reset_event_listeners(){
       //remove event listener
        $("a").off();
//put it back event listener
        $("a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
          $(this).closest('div').fadeOut();
      });

    }
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much.